# Path increment, gradient and total differential

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

I have trouble proving that in any coordinate system the total differential is equal to the inner product of gradient and path increment in that coordinate syste,.

$$dU=\vec{\nabla U}.\vec{dr}$$

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of $U$ is defined as
$$
\nabla U=(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x},\frac{\partial U}{\partial y},\frac{\partial U}{\partial z})
$$
and the path increment is
$$
d\vec{r}=(dx,dy,dz)
$$
The dot product between the two yields
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}dz = dU
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to prove it for any coordinate system not just Cartesian coordinate system. The proof should be general and independent of the type of the coordinate system.

Comment: Yes this is indeed not a rigorous proof, however it gives you the intuition on why it may be true in general.